# Average movie rankings

Tags: python, performance, statistics, mapreduce, apache-spark

Given a list of tuples of the form, `(a, b, c)`, is there a more direct or optimized for calculating the average of all the `c's` with `PySpark`? Below is what I have, but I feel like there is a more direct/optimized approach?

Classic movie recommendation example, where each tuple is `(userID, movieID, rating)`. How do we get the average of all of the ratings in a direct/optimized fashion?

```
ds_movie = sc.parallelize([(1,1,2.25), (1,2,3.0), (2,1,4.5)])
total = (ds_movie
         .map(lambda (userid, movieid, rating): rating)
         .reduce(lambda x, y: x + y))
num = ds_movie.count()
average = total / num
# in this example, average = 3.25
```

Comment: average for all c? i think your answer is the fastest unless you want to calculate average rating for each movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using `mean` method:

```
ds_movie.map(lambda (userid, movieid, rating): rating).mean()
```

It is not only more concise but should have much better numerical properties (it is using a modified version of the [online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm)).

On a side note it is better to avoid tuple parameter unpacking which has been removed in Python 3. You can check [PEP-3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) for details. Instead you can use `Rating` class as follows:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import Rating

ratings = ds_movie.map(lambda xs: Rating(*xs))
ratings.map(lambda r: r.rating).mean()
```

indexing (arguably much uglier than unpacking):

```
ds_movie.map(lambda r: r[2]).mean()
```

or standard function instead of lambda expression (kind of verbose for such a simple use case):

```
def get_rating(rating):
    userid, movieid, rating = rating
    return rating

ds_movie.map(get_rating).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be more efficient to use pairs:

```
ds_movie = sc.parallelize([(1,1,2.25), (1,2,3.0), (2,1,4.5)])
sum_ratings, num_movies = ds_movie \
    .map(lambda (userid, movieid, rating): (rating, 1)) \
    .reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
average = sum_ratings / num_movies
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternate solution, but haven't really explained why your suggestion is better than the original. Could you add some benchmarks or non-performance-related justification?